# Getting collection document protected by uid via where does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my application, once the user is logged in via Firebase auth, I want to fetch additional data from my firestore database.

I do not want users to be able to look at other user's documents, therefore I created a rule for this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  function isAuthenticated() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  function userIsSelf() {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
  }

  allow read: if
  isAuthenticated()
  && userIsSelf();
}
```

In my head, what I wrote should in theory allow the current logged in user to see data only about himself, and this worked fine in the "rules playground".

However, when I try this code in in the app, I get an error: `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I think this has something to do with the way firestore fetches the data?

The way I query this is by fetching the collection `users` with a `where` that only returns users that has uid same as logged in user:

```
const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid).get().catch(err => {
    console.error('could not fetch user', err)
})

if (!querySnapshot || querySnapshot.empty) {
    dispatch('logout')
    throw new Error('Cannot find logged in user\'s data in database')
} 

const userData = querySnapshot.docs[0].data()
commit('setUser', userData)
```

I created my firestore rules to look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function isAdmin(uid) {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid)).data.role == 'admin'
    }

    // Allow admin to do everything
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if isAdmin(request.auth.uid)
    }

    // Only allow users to read/write to themselfs
    match /users/{userId} {

      function userIsSelf() {
        return request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
      function roleIsUserOrSameAsDocument() {
        return request.resource.data.role == 'user' || request.resource.data.role == resource.data.role;
      }

        allow read: if
        isAuthenticated()
        && userIsSelf();

      allow write: if
        isAuthenticated()
        && userIsSelf()
        && roleIsUserOrSameAsDocument();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't match your rules.  Your query is attempting to get all documents where the uid field matches the provided uid:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .where("uid", "==", uid)
```

But your rules are saying that users may only access the **individual document** with the ID that matches their UID.  The rule is going to reject this query every time, because it's not looking at the document ID at all, just a field.

Your rules allow this query instead:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
```

If you actually do want to allow the user to access any document where their UID matches the uid field in the document, you will need to adjust them like this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  function isAuthenticated() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  function checkDocUid() {
    return request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
  }

  allow read: if isAuthenticated() && checkDocUid();
}
```

Note that `request.auth.uid` is the currenetly auth'd user's uid and `request.resource.data.uid` is the value of the uid field in the document.

Always remember that your query must match the rules exactly, and that [security rules are not filters](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense. I was unaware of the `.doc()` prototype. This is exactly what I wanted. This way I also don't need to do `.docs[0].data()`. Awesome! 